# How to handle back button on iOS, using Phonegap?

Tags: ios, cordova, back-button

I know that Phonegap has an [event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton) for back button, but it's only available for Android.
I must say that I don't have any iOS device in hands, don't know if them have a different behavior to "go back".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had one, you'd know that the iPhone doesn't have a back button.

Comment: Then, how is done the back behavior? Only by application's interface?